# how to draw a tree digram in syntax

Tags: syntax-trees

I am having trouble drawing a syntax tree for 2 sentences and I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
The sentences are:
a.  Where will you put your car?
b.  Dave told Bill the rumor that John ran out the door

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not only off-topic but too broad to get a good answer here. There are various different models of syntax, and each will get you a different tree.

Comment: Assuming you're doing constituency rather than dependency grammar, though, this post might help you: https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/100357884082/how-to-draw-syntax-trees-part-1-so-you-asked